# objective-c Derived class may not respond to base class method

Tags: objective-c, compiler-warnings

I have derived from a 3rd party class, and when I attempt to call a method in the base class, I get the x may not respond to y compiler warning.

How can I remove the warning?

Repro:

```
@interface ThirdPartyBaseClass : NSObject {}
+(id)build;
-(void)doStuff;
@end

@implementation ThirdPartyBaseClass
+(id) build{
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
-(void)doStuff{ 
}
@end

@interface MyDerivedClass : ThirdPartyBaseClass {}
+(id)buildMySelf;
@end

@implementation MyDerivedClass
+(id)buildMySelf{
    self = [ThirdPartyBaseClass build];
    [self doStuff]; // compiler warning here - 'MyDerivedClass' may not respond to '+doStuff'
return self;
}
@end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a class method (preceded by the '+'), 'self' is not an instance of the class; 'self' is the Class object, which only responds to Class methods, not instance methods. If you're building an instance so you can call `doStuff` on it and return it, you'll need to use a separate variable:

```
+ (id) buildMySelf
{
   MyDerivedClass *myDerivedClassInstance;

   myDerivedClassInstance = [self build];
   [myDerivedClassInstance doStuff];

   return myDerivedClassInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`-(void)doStuff` is an instance method, but you are calling it on what the compiler thinks is the class. 
The compiler believes self to be typed as as a Class, and not as a `ThirdPartyBaseClass` object

Try

```
@implementation MyDerivedClass
+(id)buildMySelf{
    id other = [ThirdPartyBaseClass build];
    [other doStuff];
    return other;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing `buildMySelf` to:

```
+(id)buildMySelf{
      self = [MyDerivedClass build];
      [self doStuff];
      return self;
}
```

Using `[ThirdPartyBaseClass build];` produces an instance of `ThirdPartyBaseClass`, not `MyDerivedClass`.

Comment: This still produces the 'may not respond to...' warning